# Plotting time series information with missing date values

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, time-series, seaborn

I have the following dataset:

```
dataset.head(7)
Transaction_date     Product   Product Code  Description    
2019-01-01           A         123           A123
2019-01-02           B         267           B267
2019-01-09           B         267           B267
2019-02-11           C         139           C139
2019-02-11           A         125           C125 
2019-02-12           C         139           C139
2019-02-12           A         123           A123
```

The dataset stores transaction information, for which a transaction date is available. In other words, not for all days, data is available.
Ultimately, I want to create a time series plot, showing me the number of transactions per day.

So far, I have done a simple countplot:

```
ax = sns.countplot(x=dataset["Transaction_date"],data=dataset)
```

This plot shows me the dates, where a transaction happened. But I would prefer to see also the dates, where no transaction has happened in a plot, preferably shown as 0.

I have tried the following, but retrieve an error message:

```
groupbydate = dataset.groupby("Transaction_date")
ax = sns.tsplot(x="Transaction_date",y="Product",data=groubydate.fillna(0))
```

But I get the error 
`cannot label index with a null key`
Due to restrictions, I can only use `seaborn 0.8.1`

Answer (score 0):

I believe `reindex` should work for you:

```
# First convert the index to datetime
dataset.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(dataset.index)

# Then reindex! You can also select the min and max of the index for the limits
dataset= dataset.reindex(pd.date_range("2019-01-01", "2019-02-12"), fill_value="NaN")
```

Comment: Thank you. I have forget to mention that there might be index duplicates in the dataset. I have found them using `dataset[dataset.index.duplicated()]`. This means, that for one transaction date various products can retrieved. So, if I apply: `dataset=dataset.reindex(pd.date_range("2019-01-01", "2019-02-12"), fill_value="NaN")`, I get an error : `cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`

Answer (score -1):

You can drop the rows containing NaN values using [`pandas.DataFrame.dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html), and then plot the chart. For example:

`dataset.dropna(thresh=2)`

will drop all rows where there are at least two NaN values.

You may also want to fill the NaN values using [`pandas.DataFrame.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)

Comment: Hi, I actually would like to keep the NaN values, so that I see the dates, when nothing has been transacted.